# How to send push notification with image in react-native android using rnfirebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am sending notification only and notification-data push notifications successfully in android using rnfirebase.
How can i send data only push notification with image as I am following 
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/receiving-notifications

Answer (score 6):

If you are displaying your notifications with `firebase.notifications().displayNotification`, you can use [Notification.BigPictureStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigPictureStyle) in order to display an image in your notification by calling [setBigPicture](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/reference/AndroidNotification#setBigPicture) on `notification.android`.

Example:

```
const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
    .setTitle(title)

notification.android.setBigPicture('url of your image')

firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification)
```