# React Native Local Notification with icon from url

Tags: firebase, react-native, notifications, react-native-push-notification

I am developing a react native app with chatting functionality. I use [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) for the notifications which are sent from my django server using [fcm-django](https://github.com/xtrinch/fcm-django) plugin. For receiving the notifications in the client I use [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase). I send a data type message (not notification, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)) and from the app, when the message is received, I am creating a local notification using [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification).

What I want now is to be able to change the notification icon (`largeIcon`, see properties [here](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#local-notifications)) and set it to be the profile image of the user who sent the message.

[image]

```
profile_image = 'http://...'

PushNotification.localNotification({
        title: from_user.username,
        message: message_text,
        priority: "max",
        importance: "max",
        largeIcon: "???"   <--------
});
```

The problem is that the `largeIcon` property (as far as I know) accepts a string with the name of the icon that is located in the  app's folder (`res/mipmap` folder for android etc.) while I have a url for the image. What should I do?

- Should I download the image and save it in that folder (if it is possible)?
- Should I use notification type when sending the message from server?
- Should I try another react native plugin for local notifications?

I am currently concerned for making it work at least on Android. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it using the react-native-firebase plugin I already had installed. It also has functions for creating local notifications, and for the icon it accepts url. I found out about this from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52537713/7053344) and then read more about creating local notifications from the react-native-firebase [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/displaying-notifications).